# Multiple match of items that follows a string with one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get multiple matches (that's the easy part) only if there's certain text at the beginning

**It has to be done on the server-side so no jQuery can be used**

An example will be: I want to get all the matching HTML elements inside a parent one. So if I have a parent called "gallery" that has multiple "image" elements inside, I want to get only those elements.

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="item" />
    <img src="item" />
    <img src="item" />
    <img src="item" />
</div>
```

Another example will be with a JSON (I can't parse it so I need a regex). In the JSON case I have the following:

```js
{
  "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
    "mage/gallery/gallery": {
      "data": [{
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }, {
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }, {
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }, {
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }, {
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }, {
        "full": "https://google.com"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to match all the `full` elements (`full":"(.+?)"`) but only if they're followed by `data-gallery-role`. The problem is that a regex like: `role.+?full":"(.+?)"` will only match the first one

Comment: Why do you "need" a regex? With JS or jQuery it's super easy (`$(".gallery img[src='items']")`). As for the JSON, why can't you parse it?

Comment: Yup, you want jquery or cheerio for parsing html

Comment: Hey, no, I cannot use jQuery since I'm parsing the HTML on the server-side not client-side

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two steps. First match the entire parent element, then match for children inside the captured group. For example:

```
<div class="gallery">\n(.*\n)*<\/div>
```

Then, something like this on the matched result:

```
<img src="(.*)" \/>
```